# Need syntax to carry jquery filled field value to next form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I incorporated a jquery type-ahead autocomplete script into an existing search page that consisted of 2 dropdown auto submit search boxes. Those auto submits where accomplished using onchange and they were self referencing. As soon as the user selected the category in the first drop down, the page returned with the second drop down filled with an ever increasing number of options. The page submitted using the following code;

```
<form name="nav"><select name="platform" id="platform" onChange="document.location.href=document.nav.platform.options[document.nav.platform.selectedIndex].value">
```

Upon completion of the user selecting the first drop down, the page returns to itself and narrows the results for the second drop down. The problem was the second drop down was getting too big for users to maneuver.

Without knowing jquery I've been able to graft the type ahead autocomplete script into the existing search form for the replacement of the second drop down. However, I cannot figure out how to carry the value of the jquery search forward to the same page to have a php statement execute it.

The following jquery populates the second field with the id of the record I need to carry forward. This is the function from jquery;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
```

This is the html at the bottom of the page that ends up containing the id of the record I need going forward.

```
<div>
    <form name="dash3.php">
        <div>
            Start typing the name of the item, select the correct title when it appears:
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="papa" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
            <input type="hidden" value="?list=1" />
        </div>

        <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

The php sitting at the top of the page is looking for this to trigger the add;

```
if ($_GET['list']==1) {
```

I need to set 'list' equal to 1 (you can see I tried that with the hidden input) and the php variable named $vid set to the contents of the jquery type ahead results so that the submit button will carry the values forward and the php script will execute the add. I've tried hidden fields, I've tried grafting pieces of jquery together but I don't have a solid base in java or jquery and I can't think of another way to do this. I've gotten a little further with each request, I hope that I've framed the question well enough to get it this go around! Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

From first glance, it looks like you are updating the "inputString" input with a null value on blur?  You have not passed anything to your "fill" function.

JQuery provides simple event handlers that would clean that part up a bit.

```
$(function(){ // <--This waits until load to initialize handlers
    $("#inputString").blur(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```